# Angular Cli ng serve don't work

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

When I try to run `ng serve`
I got this error :

```
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: 
TypeError
: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. 
Error: Ty
peError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mounadi\angular2-quickstart\node_modules\@ng
tools\webpack\src\index.js:14:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mounadi\angular2-quickstart\node_modules\@an
gular\cli\tasks\eject.js:10:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I tried to uninstall *@angular/cli* and install *@angular/cli@latest* and I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to start with angular CLI.

First update node version:

1. So, first check your node version by typing command `node -v`.
2. If node version is lower than 6.x.x then update it because angular CLI requires node version to be higher than 6.x.x. To update node version run the below command.

   `nvm install <new version> --reinstall-packages-from=<old version>`

   **`Ex: nvm install 7.10.0 --reinstall-packages-from=5.1.0`**

   Then run command: `nvm use 7.10.0`
3. After this run command `npm install -g @angular/cli` to install **Angular CLI**.
4. Then `ng new my-new-project` to create new project.
5. Then `cd my-new-project` to go inside created project directory.
6. And then finally `ng serve` to run your app.

**Extra:**
To update your angular 2 project into angular 4 project run below command:

```
    * On Linux/Mac: npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-    
                     server,router,animations}@next --save server,router,animations}@next --save

     * On Windows: npm install @angular/common@next @angular/compiler@next @angular/compiler-cli@next @angular/core@next 
                   @angular/forms@next @angular/http@next @angular/platform-browser@next @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next 
                   @angular/platform-server@next @angular/  router@next @angular/animations@next --save
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, installing with `@next` right now will install the 5.0.0 beta. Use `@latest` if you want to stick with 4.x.